# how to get the params value from a radio button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

```
<% @hotelUser= HotelUser.find(cookies[:user_id2])%>

<%= form_for(:hotelUser,:url=>{:controller=>'orders',:action=>'show'}) do |hotelUser|%>                 
  <%= @hotelUser.address1%> 
  <%= hotelUser.radio_button :address1,:value=>@hotelUser.address1 ,:checked=>true%>&nbsp;SELECT ADDRESS   
  <%= @hotelUser.address2%>
  <%= hotelUser.radio_button :address1,:value=>@hotelUser.address2 ,:checked=>true%>&nbsp;SELECT ADDRESS 
  <%= hotelUser.submit("PROCEED TO PAYMENT",{:action=>'show'})%>
<%end%>
```

I have two radio button in my page with the same name. The problem is that I am not getting the `params[:address1]` `value` in the `orders/show` page. I need this value to further processing of my application.

Answer (score 0):

See your server params sent with the request, it will be nested within params[:hotelUser][:address1] .One more thing I'm not sure but i think it will return an array of two values the first radio button and the second since they you have two with the same name.

Best way is to check the sent params with the request and you will figure out how you can get the values of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use radio_button_tag instead of radio_button:

`<% @hotelUser= HotelUser.find(cookies[:user_id2])%>`

`<%= form_for(:hotelUser,:url=>{:controller=>'orders',:action=>'show'}) do |hotelUser|%>`
  `<%= @hotelUser.address1%>

`<%= radio_button_tag :address1,@hotelUser.address1 %>&nbsp;SELECT ADDRESS
  <%= @hotelUser.address2%>`

`<%= radio_button_tag :address1,@hotelUser.address2 %>&nbsp;SEL
ECT ADDRESS`
  `<%= hotelUser.submit("PROCEED TO PAYMENT",{:action=>'show'})%>
<%end%>`